# Hyperledger byfn issue, chaincode instantiation failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm running hyper-ledger fabric example Build your first network on linux without Internet access. Network up and chaincode is installed. But encounter error when instantiation chaincode. Error info like below. Since it's on inner Server, so there's no way I can access Internet. Can anyone explain what's going on on this step and what can I do in an offline way?

```
===================== Chaincode is installed on remote peer PEER2 =====================
Instantiating chaincode on org2/peer2...
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp

CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051

2017-09-07 20:15:16.984 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP

2017-09-07 20:15:16.984 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity

2017-09-07 20:15:16.987 UTC [chaincodeCmd] 

checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2017-09-07 20:15:16.987 UTC [chaincodeCmd]

checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc

2017-09-07 20:15:16.988 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: plaintext: 0A91070A6708031A0C08D4D1C6CD0510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363

2017-09-07 20:15:16.988 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: digest: 17D7F0C37473394040F19251CCA253B1ECA95F7AD65AF27EFA92DE1F10D94A9B

Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error starting container: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hyperledger/fabric-baseos/manifests/x86_64-0.3.2: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:48951->[::1]:53: read: connection refuse

Usage:
  peer chaincode instantiate [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be execut
```

Comment: How did you get the other Docker images on your machine if you can't access the Internet?

Comment: docker save  & docker load

Comment: So you'll also need the hyperledger/fabric-baseos:x86_64-0.3.2 image as well (it looks like you are using Fabric v1.0.x?)

Comment: Did I need to change any config file? I have got the fabric-baseos:x86_64-0.4.6. Is that version OK?

Comment: You should get fabric-baseos:x86_64-0.3.2 as that is the version supported with Fabric v1.0.x.  If you move to Fabric v1.1.0, then 0.4.6 is OK

Comment: Thank you so much. Without your help, I can not solve this problem